# How to get Notified when a background program get closed in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

the Program entry point function is WinMain
and it doesn't create a Window so it runs in the background.
I want to get a notification when the program is closed like: by the user through task manager or through system shutdown so I can save some progress.

something like the windows messages WM_QUITE but I can't access that as far as I know cuz i don't create a window

Comment: Instead of this when you spawn a background process have it wait till the process is completed.

Comment: You can either attach to the process using the Debugger APIs and [WaitForDebugEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-waitfordebugevent) will give you a process exit event. Or you can add the process to a Job Object and monitor completion port callbacks see [JOBOBJECT_ASSOCIATE_COMPLETION_PORT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-jobobject_associate_completion_port)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no window, you may consider modifying the program registration as a DLL service plug-in.

The service also has no window and executes in the background.

The process is closed. Only the kernel callback knows that a process is killed. There will be no event whether the R3 process is closed.

Unless you have another process intermittently scanning the process list continuously.

Registering as a service at least you can receive event callbacks when your service is stopped by others.

CreateServiceW

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/services/installing-a-service

Answer (score 0):

Is the background program something that your own code started, using CreateProcess()? If so, you can use the process handle (hProcess in the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure) in functions like WaitForSingleObject() etc. to check if the process still runs.

Comment: no the background program is my own code